Axler Theorem 5.33: arguing that $U \cap V = \{0\}$.
I'm having trouble understanding a key step in Axler's proof of Theorem 5.33. The theorem states:

Let $F = \mathbb{R}$, $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space, and $T: V \to V$ a linear map. Let $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $b^2 < 4c$. Then $\text{dim } \text{null}(T^2 + bT + cI)$ is an even number.

In the first half of the proof, he restricts $T$ to $\text{null}(T^2 + bT + cI)$ and proves that $T$ then has no eigenvectors. I'm fine with this step. I'm not completely clear with the next two paragraphs. He first says:

Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$ and has the largest dimension among all subspaces of $V$ that are invariant under $T$ and have even dimension.

My first question is: how do we even know that such a $U$ exists? I can think of a trivial case which bounds the dimension of $U$. One is $V$ itself (which here has been to replaced by $\text{null}(T^2 + bT + cI)$, though I don't think I know for certain (yet) that it has even dimension. On the other extreme is the trivial subspace, which has even dimension $0$, but I don't think that is what Axler had in mind.
After this, he proceeds. If $U = V$, the proof is done: I'm ok with that, because then $V$ has even dimension. If not, there exists $w \in V - U$. He lets $W = \text{span}(w, Tw)$, which must have dimension 2. Otherwise, $w$ is an eigenvector of $T$, which he proved in the first paragraph does not exist. He shows that $W$ is invariant under $T$, which I'm ok with, but I don't understand how he found that $U \cap W = \{0\}$. He states:

where $U \cap W = \{0\}$ because otherwise $U \cap W$ would be a one-dimensional subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$ (impossible because $T$ has no eigenvectors).

I understand that $U \cap W$ is a subspace of both $U$ and $W$, and by a previous theorem, must therefore be finite-dimensional with dimension less than or equal to the dimension of $U$ and less than or equal to the dimension of $W$. So it's dimension is no larger than $2$, certainly. But Axler seems to rule out that $U \cap W$ could have dimension $2$. If that were the case, then $U \cap W = W$ (it's a subspace of $W$ with the same dimension as it). I think the idea is that this is a contradiction because $w \not \in U$.
As for the case where $U \cap W$ is one-dimensional, I think I am able to follow. Any one-dimensional invariant subspace gives an eigenvector of $T$, which was earlier shown to not exist, so it can't have dimension $1$.
My apologies if this question is rather messy. I would really appreciate some help with parsing this proof.

Since the trivial subspace has even dimension and is invariant, the set
$$S :=\{\mathrm{dim}(U) : U \text{ is invariant under } T, \mathrm{dim}(U) \text{ is even}\}$$
is nonempty.
This set is also finite since it consists only of integers, and its elements cannot exceed $\mathrm{dim}(V)$. Any nonempty finite set of integers (or real numbers, for that matter) has a maximum, so let $m$ be the maximum of $S$. Then by the definition of $S$ there is exists an invariant subspace $U$ such that $m=\mathrm{dim}(U)$, and we choose such $U$ moving forward in the proof. $U$ is not necessarily unique, but that's fine for our purposes.
You are correct in that if $\mathrm{dim}(U\cap W)=2$ then $U\cap W=W$. Then since $w\in W$ by definition, we will have $w\in U$ but this is indeed contradictory to the choice of $w\in V-U$.
